# How to avoid accessing one app controller from another app

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have 2  cakephp  directory in my server in separate path . Cakephp application 1 is located in  /var/www/html/app1/v11/. this application can accessed via http://example.com . Cakephp application 2 is located in /var/www/html/ app2/ v12/app. This application can accessed via sub.example.com/app2 . Cakephp app 2 having some controllers/models/views of cakephp app 1 excepted 2 new controllers.

When accessing sub.example.com/app2/comps/list  url , it shows some undefined error

```
 Notice (8): Undefined variable: res [APP/Controller/CompsController.php, line 681]
 Code Context
$stack  =   array()
CompsController::trending() - APP/Controller/CompsController.php, line 681
 ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - /var/www/html/app1/v11/lib/Cake/Controller      /Controller.php, line 488
  Dispatcher::_invoke() - /var/www/html/app1/v11/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 103
```

Dispatcher::dispatch() - /var/www/html/app1/v11/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 85
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96
Null

Ie it accessing controller from v11  app. How to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the settings in your `webroot/index.php` are incorrect.

Specifically, this line - make sure it's different for each app, and points to the correct location.

```
define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
```

Comment: i checked  APP_DIR is pointing app folder,ROOT is pointing  /var/www/html/app2/v12/